# Examples for using latest version of Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I'm new to Lucene and want to call it directly from my Java code in a Maven environment. I have tried for some time to find working examples that I can download and run. The latest tutorial on the official site is 2013 - Lucene 3.* https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/lucene/LuceneFAQ#LuceneFAQ-HowdoIstartusingLucene?. The current latest version in Maven is `8.5.1` . Most non-official tutorials on the web do not contain version numbers or Fully Qualified Names. Lucene appears to change its API, syntax, and names at frequent intervals so that compile errors, ClassNotFound, and deleted methods occur. 
I'd like to know:

- the current stable version
- the Lucene packages involved (is a `lucene-query` package required?)
- pointers to code that works in 2020 with these versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The home page for the latest version of the documentation is [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_5_1/index.html). This includes links to all the javadoc sections (different sections for different libraries).

It also includes links to some current working code examples (yes, there are breaking changes from pre-8 to 8+). The wiki can be unreliable in this regard, as you have seen.

The [main demo](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_5_1/demo/index.html) is probably the best place to start to see working code examples.

Specifically, see the [how to index](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_5_1/demo/src-html/org/apache/lucene/demo/IndexFiles.html) and [how to search](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_5_1/demo/src-html/org/apache/lucene/demo/SearchFiles.html) examples.

Which packages you need depends entirely on what you are trying to do. It's unlikely that you will need the spatial analysis package, for example, unless you *know you need it*.

My POM typically includes these:

```
<properties>
    <lucene.version>8.5.0</lucene.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>        
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>          
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>${lucene.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
        <version>${lucene.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
        <version>${lucene.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-icu</artifactId>
        <version>${lucene.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Sometimes I also use these:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-suggest</artifactId>
    <version>${lucene.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-highlighter</artifactId>
    <version>${lucene.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I was looking for. Will download and test and return..

Comment: The demo isn't available under Maven AFAICS but it can be copied.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust - The demo source code is available in the source release, downloadable from [this page](https://lucene.apache.org/core/downloads.html). Also, separately, the binary release (same page) includes the GUI tool `Luke` - very useful for inspecting index data, if you're not already familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I downloaded the source code and extracted the demo, but I hadn't seen `Luke` . I was going to ask about inspecting the index but you have just answered it. However I may  need to find the latest API calls

Comment: Have built `Luke` with:

`cd    <somewhere>/lucene-8.5.2/luke`
then 

    `mkdir ~/.ant`
then
    `ant compile jar run`

The `mkdir` seemed to be  necessary to create the ant directory YMMV

Comment: @peter.murray.rust - Sounds like you don't need it, but there is a pre-built Luke in the binary release JAR. That has launch scripts for Windows and Linux.