# search with lucene's QueryParser while setting fieldName to "*" failed?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, query-parser

I want to search through all fields in the index by lucene, and I learned to do this by writting the code like this:

```
//Create a parser that searches through all fields
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser("*", new StandardAnalyzer()); 

//Specify the search terms
String queryString = "search terms";

//Create the query to search through all fields
Query query = queryParser.parse(queryString); 

//Execute the query and get the results
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader); 
TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, 100); 
ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs; 

//Iterate through the results
for (ScoreDoc hit : hits) { 
  Document doc = searcher.doc(hit.doc); 
  //Process the document
}
```

when I setted first parameter of QueryParser Constructor to "*", like the code above, and I got nothing from the TopDocs(which I had expected to search through all fields of the documents I'd write into the index and returnd all matching documents), the "hits.totalHits" returns 0.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code or how to write code using QueryParser to search through all fields in the index?

Thanks!

Comment: Wildcards are for terms, not for field names. And also, the `QueryParser` [constructor](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_5_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParser.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer)) in your code is using that first parameter to define the _default_ field name (the field name to use if you do not provide one explicitly).

Comment: Each document in a Lucene index may have different field names. You can search in Stack Overflow for ways to access all the field names in each document. Here is [one approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62158685/12567365). Note also the comment in that answer about handling deleted docs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And I know to use QueryParser to search either sigle field or multi fields by lucene. But I Just don't know how to search for every fields in documents I'd insert to the index. I learned to pass `*` to QueryParser as default field by reading the source code of `ElasticSearch-7.10.2, QueryStringQueryBuilder.java:876`. When using the query_string of ES and default field is not specified, ElasticSearch will call the constructor of class QueryStringQueryParser, which inherited from lucene.QueryParser, and will use `*` as the first parameter.

Comment: The behavior i talked above has also been decleared in [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) in `default_field`, thanks again.

Comment: If you are looking for an ElasticSearch answer, you can ask an ElasticSearch question with the relevant tags.

Comment: thanks for advice, btw I'm using lucene-9.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried the [MultiFieldQueryParser](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/MultiFieldQueryParser.html#parse-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer-)?
In this case you have to specify all fields where to want to search on.

Comment: Yes, I had tried to use `MultiFieldQueryParser ` and specify all the fields and it worked. I think maybe it's my wrong usage of `QueryParser`, and it just doesn't support to use `*` as default field name. But still, I'm confused about the usage of passing `*` to QueryParser as the first parameter from the ElasticSearch source code.