# Using Lucene to index an Apache Jena Fuseki Server deployed as a WAR file via tomcat

Tags: tomcat, lucene, war, jena, fuseki

I am trying to run full-text indexing on a Fuseki server using Lucene. The Fuseki server is version 3.15.0 and is deployed as a WAR file using Apache tomcat 9.0.24.

I have tried following [these](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/text-query.html) instructions to get Lucene running, however, it appears that they are written to work with the .jar distribution of Fueski.

Currently, the server has about 1.2TB of triples (a subset of human entities from Wikidata including their labels).

When I try to initiate the service using the assembly file below, nothing appears to be indexed

`11:13:51 INFO  textindexer :: 0 (0 per second) properties indexed`

This is the assembler file being used

```
@prefix :        <http://localhost/jena_example/#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix tdb:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
@prefix text:    <http://jena.apache.org/text#> .
@prefix skos:    <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
@prefix fuseki:  <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
@prefix wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#> .
@prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> .
@prefix tdb2:    <http://jena.apache.org/2016/tdb#> .

[] rdf:type fuseki:Server ;
   fuseki:services (
     :myservice
   ) .

:myservice rdf:type fuseki:Service ;
    fuseki:name                       "wikidata_index" ;     # e.g : `s-query --service=http://localhost:3030/myds "select * ..."`
    fuseki:serviceQuery               "query" ;    # SPARQL query service
    fuseki:serviceUpdate              "update" ;   # SPARQL update service
    fuseki:serviceUpload              "upload" ;   # Non-SPARQL upload service
    fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore "data" ;     # SPARQL Graph store protocol (read and write)
    fuseki:dataset                    :text_dataset ;
    .

## ---------------------------------------------------------------

# A TextDataset is a regular dataset with a text index.
:text_dataset rdf:type     text:TextDataset ;
    text:dataset   :mydataset ; # <-- replace `:my_dataset` with the desired URI
    text:index     <#indexLucene> ;
.

# A TDB dataset used for RDF storage
:mydataset rdf:type      tdb2:DatasetTDB2 ; # <-- replace `:my_dataset` with the desired URI - as above
    tdb2:location "/data/wikidata/fuseki-db/wikidata_index" ;
    tdb2:unionDefaultGraph true ;
.

# Text index description
<#indexLucene> a text:TextIndexLucene ;
    text:directory <file:/data/wikidata/fuseki-db/lucene_index_wikidata_attempt3> ;
    text:entityMap <#entMap> ;
    text:storeValues true ;
    text:analyzer [ a text:StandardAnalyzer ] ;
    text:queryAnalyzer [ a text:KeywordAnalyzer ] ;
    text:queryParser text:AnalyzingQueryParser ;
    text:propLists (
     [ text:propListProp wikibase:label ;
       text:props ( rdfs:label
                          skos:altLabel
                          skos:prefLabel ) ;
     ]
     [ text:propListProp wikibase:description ;
       text:props ( schema:description ) ;
     ]
     ) ;
    text:multilingualSupport true ;
.

# Entity map (see documentation for other options)
<#entMap> a text:EntityMap ;
    text:defaultField     "label" ;
    text:entityField      "uri" ;
    text:uidField         "uid" ;
    text:langField        "lang" ;
    text:graphField       "graph" ;
    text:map (
        [ text:field "label" ;
          text:predicate skos:prefLabel ]
     ) .
```

Is there anything wrong with the above set-up, or an easier way to run full text indexing (using Lucene or otherwise) over a Fuseki triplestore deployed as a `.WAR` file?

EDIT: The index has been built (fixed typo in the predicate label) but am now unsure how to use the indexing data that has been generated.

Comment: After your edit, this feels like a completely new question. What have you tried? Where are you hitting problems? Can you show us your code?

Comment: Having said that, have you looked at the example "how to search" code provided by Lucene? A link to the demo can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62061712/examples-for-using-latest-version-of-lucene/62064733#62064733). The same demo code is also available in [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/master/lucene/demo/src/java/org/apache/lucene/demo).